# How to monkey patch alias_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I have a database with a field 'update' corresponding to updated_at.
The database is not only used by a rails application and it's not possible to migrate the field currently.

In my model, I want to make an alias on the attribute :

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute 'updated_at', 'update'
  ...
end
```

But this call the update method of the model.

So i found the alias_attribute definition here : [github code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb)

I want to monkey patch this for something like :

```
def self.alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)
  module_eval <<-STR, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{new_name}; self.attributes[#{old_name}]; end
    def #{new_name}?; self.attributes[#{old_name}?; end
    def #{new_name}=(v); self.attributes[#{old_name} = v; end
  STR
end
```

How can i make this work?